# Datapusher with missing values and mixed (srting/numeric) data

Tags: r, ckan

I have a csv file which has 31,989 rows of data.

The columns are all numeric data, but some of the cells have missing values, which the author has coded as NA (which is common when using R for analysis).  CKAN seems to be having trouble with the NA.

If I load up the original file, it begins pushing the data to datastore, but stops part way through, and the preview only shows 3750 records.  If you edit (manage) the resource and go to the DataStore tab, it shows this error:

```
Error: The data was invalid (for example: a numeric value is out of range or was inserted into a text field).
HTTP status code: 409
Response: {"help": "https://datastore.landcareresearch.co.nz/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create", "success": false, "error": {"message": "The data was invalid (for example: a numeric value is out of r...
Requested URL: https://datastore.landcareresearch.co.nz/api/3/action/datastore_create
```

However, if I recode the NA as -9999, then the file uploads fine, and all 31,989 records are previewed.

Is there any way around this so we can retain NA for missing values (as used in R)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `ckanr` https://github.com/ropensci/ckanr/ by chance?

Comment: @sckott Not actively yet, but I have looked into it had had a small play, and it is something we will use in future I am sure - hence wanting to know about this NA issue.  I am a novice R user (my role actually isn't analysis of data - now more in role of guiding/facilitating for others around data management, I used to do analysis many years ago pre R).  We’ve setup CKAN, and lots of staff here use R, so ckanr is an obvious step.

Comment: sounds good, looks like there's an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do exactly what you want because the DataStore is more or less a 1:1 link to a database table. In Postgresql you also can't insert text into a numeric column. I've just tried different forms of missing values in a CSV file (null, NULL, None and leaving the value out completely, i.e. field1,,field3) - what works is leaving the value out:
http://beta.ckan.org/dataset/tests/resource/ae878fea-75c9-48ea-93ba-59df3536406a

You can see the column still gets treated as numeric:
http://beta.ckan.org/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=ae878fea-75c9-48ea-93ba-59df3536406a&limit=5

Original file:
http://beta.ckan.org/dataset/ceaa03b5-c9ae-4fdd-908d-8c461cba07ea/resource/ae878fea-75c9-48ea-93ba-59df3536406a/download/quicktest.csv

Maybe that would be satisfactory? You could just do a find/replace 'NA'->'' in the CSV file. The only other option would be to force the column to be text by using quotes or a text value earlier in the file, but I don't think that's what you want, and it would cause problems with views in CKAN.